# Inline asm: operand type mismatch for `in'

Tags: c, assembly, io, x86, att

I got the error

> Error: operand type mismatch for `in'

The line generating this is:

```
inb %%eax, %%edx
```

I tried these: `inb %%eax, $0x00000064` and `inb %%eax, $0x64`.

But neither of them did change the output. I also tried with `in` instead of `inb`, but I'm taking shots in the dark at this point.

Any ideas?

Comment: Operand order is reversed in AT&T syntax, so it should be `$0x64,%eax`. `%edx` isn't a valid source operand for `in` (but `%dx` is).

Comment: will %dx pick up the value from the %edx register?

Comment: `dx` is the lower half of `edx`.

Comment: we are using 32bit registers in x86 architecture, does this still apply?

Answer (score 3):

"in**b**" means that you execute a mnemonic command "in" on the operands of size byte (8-bit). inw is for words (16-bit), inl is for long words (32-bit) and inq is for quad (on 64 bit machines). The %eax register is 32-bit, which consists of %ax (16-bit). The %ax register, in its turn, consists of high 8 bits (%ah) and low 8 bits (%al). Thus, if you are to use "inb", you should use %al or %ah, e.g.,

```
inb %%al, %%dl # from source %%al 8-bit to destination %%dl 8-bit.
```

To use "in" with %eax, you need to append "l" to the command (or to omit the letter as some compilers can infer the type). That is,

```
inl %%eax, %%edx
```

should do fine.

Comment: The port number can be an immediate, and has to be DX if it's a register.  Not DL or EDX.  (I/O addresses are 16-bit, separate from physical or virtual address-space).  Also, no, `inb` can only us AL, not AH.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in (Intel's manual uses Intel syntax, so the AT&T equivalent is `inb %%dx, %%al` or `inb $8, %%al`.

Comment: IDK what I was thinking when I upvoted this years ago, but neither of the code blocks shown are valid.

Answer (score 0):

AT&T syntax is `in src, dst`, where src is a port number and the destination is AL, AX, EAX, according to the size of I/O access you want to make.  (`inb`/`inw`/`inl`).  64-bit IO size is *not* available, even in 64-bit mode.

The port number can be an immediate like `inb $0x64, %al`, but has to be DX if it's a register.
(I/O addresses are 16-bit, separate from physical or virtual address-space).

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in - Intel's manual uses Intel syntax, so the AT&T equivalent is

```
asm volatile("inb %%dx, %%al" : "=a"(byte) : "d"(portnum));
```

Or better, let the compiler pick immediate vs. register for you by using an `"Nd"((uint16_t)port)` constraint, and use the `%1` operand instead of hard-coding `%%dx`.

See [Porting AT&T inline-asm inb / outb wrappers to work with gcc -masm=intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962333/porting-att-inline-asm-inb-outb-wrappers-to-work-with-gcc-masm-intel) for working AT&T-syntax wrappers, and also working Intel-syntax wrapper functions.

To also make it work with `gcc -masm=intel`, you can use [dialect alternatives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) as shown in Michael Petch's answer:

```
uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;  // 8-bit type will get "=a" to pick AL
    asm volatile ( "inb {%[port], %[retreg] | %[retreg], %[port]}"
                   : [retreg]"=a"(ret)
                   : [port]"Nd"(port) );
    return ret;
}
```

Letting the compiler expand `%0` to `%al` or `al` according to syntax mode saves us the trouble.

Answer (score -2):

Intel gave very little information about The i/o instruction set
..
Nevertheless you are to deal with a port address or a register then extract the input from that address.

in dest, source

Note your destination is a physical address

So you must point to that address

> in $0x8, %al ;

**Note Intel warns about 0FH to 0FFH not to be used**

This puts the ax lower 8-bits into the physical address 0x8

Comment: `in` *reads* (not writes) from I/O space, so its only destination is AL or AX. **I/O space is separate from physical address space.** That's why `mov 8, %al` is different from `in $8, %al` even in real mode with DS segment base = 0.  (`in`/`out` don't care about segment registers).  You could say that `in $8, %al` gets 8 bits from I/O port `8`, loading the result into the lower 8 bits of AX.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).