# Porting AT&T inline-asm inb / outb wrappers to work with gcc -masm=intel

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, osdev

I am currently working on my x86 OS. I tried implementing the inb function from [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples) and it gives me `` Error: Operand type mismatch for `in' ``.

This may also be the same with `outb` or `io_wait`.

I am using Intel syntax (`-masm=intel`) and I don't know what to do.

Code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "ioaccess.h"

uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile ( "inb %1, %0"
                   : "=a"(ret)
                   : "Nd"(port) );
    return ret;
}
```

With AT&T syntax this does work.

---

**For outb I'm having a different problem after reversing the operands:**

```
void io_wait(void)
{
    asm volatile ( "outb $0x80, %0" : : "a"(0) );
}
```

`` Error: operand size mismatch for `out' ``

Comment: Your followup added in an edit was related enough that we can turn this into one potentially-useful question to go with MichaelPetch's answer that covers inb and outb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use `-masm=intel` you will need to insure that your inline assembly is in Intel syntax. Intel syntax is dst, src (AT&T syntax is reverse). This somewhat [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961862/3857942) has some useful information on some differences between NASM's Intel variant<sup>1</sup> (not GAS's variant) and AT&T syntax:

> Information on how you can go about translating NASM Intel syntax to GAS's AT&T syntax can be found in this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961862/3857942), and a lot of useful information is provided in this [IBM article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html).
>
> [snip]
>
> In general the biggest differences are:
>
> - With AT&T syntax the source is on the left and destination is on the right and Intel is the reverse.
> - With AT&T syntax register names are prepended with a `%`
> - With AT&T syntax immediate values are prepended with a `$`
> - Memory operands are probably the  biggest difference. NASM uses *[segment:disp+base+index*scale]* instead of GAS's syntax of *segment:disp(base, index, scale)*.

The problem in your code is that source and destination operands have to be reversed from the original AT&T syntax you were working with. This code:

```
asm volatile ( "inb %1, %0"
               : "=a"(ret)
               : "Nd"(port) );
```

Needs to be:

```
asm volatile ( "inb %0, %1"
               : "=a"(ret)
               : "Nd"(port) );
```

---

Regarding your update: the problem is that in Intel syntax immediate values are not prepended with a `$`. This line is a problem:

```
asm volatile ( "outb $0x80, %0" : : "a"(0) );
```

It should be:

```
asm volatile ( "outb 0x80, %0" : : "a"(0) );
```

---

If you had a proper `outb` function you could do something like this instead:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "ioaccess.h"

uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile ( "inb %0, %1"
                   : "=a"(ret)
                   : "Nd"(port) );
    return ret;
}

void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t byte)
{
    asm volatile ( "outb %1, %0"
                   :
                   : "a"(byte),
                     "Nd"(port) );
}

void io_wait(void)
{
    outb (0x80, 0);
}
```

A slightly more complex version that supports both the AT&T and Intel [dialects](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html):

> Multiple assembler dialects in asm templates On targets such as x86,
>   GCC supports multiple assembler dialects. The -masm option controls
>   which dialect GCC uses as its default for inline assembler. The
>   target-specific documentation for the -masm option contains the list
>   of supported dialects, as well as the default dialect if the option is
>   not specified. This information may be important to understand, since
>   assembler code that works correctly when compiled using one dialect
>   will likely fail if compiled using another. See x86 Options.
>
> If your code needs to support multiple assembler dialects (for
>   example, if you are writing public headers that need to support a
>   variety of compilation options), use constructs of this form:
>
> { dialect0 | dialect1 | dialect2... }

On x86 and x86-64 targets there are two dialects. Dialect0 is AT&T syntax and Dialect1 is Intel syntax. The functions could be reworked this way:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "ioaccess.h"

uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile ( "inb {%[port], %[retreg] | %[retreg], %[port]}"
                   : [retreg]"=a"(ret)
                   : [port]"Nd"(port) );
    return ret;
}

void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t byte)
{
    asm volatile ( "outb {%[byte], %[port] | %[port], %[byte]}"
                   :
                   : [byte]"a"(byte),
                     [port]"Nd"(port) );
}

void io_wait(void)
{
    outb (0x80, 0);
}
```

I have also given the constraints symbolic names rather than using `%0` and `%1` to make the inline assembly easier to read and maintain.. From the GCC documentation each constraint has the form:

> [ [asmSymbolicName] ] constraint (cvariablename)

Where:

> asmSymbolicName
>
> Specifies a symbolic name for the operand. Reference the name in the assembler template by enclosing it in square brackets (i.e. ‘%[Value]’). The scope of the name is the asm statement that contains the definition. Any valid C variable name is acceptable, including names already defined in the surrounding code. No two operands within the same asm statement can use the same symbolic name.
>
> When not using an asmSymbolicName, use the (zero-based) position of the operand in the list of operands in the assembler template. For example if there are three output operands, use ‘%0’ in the template to refer to the first, ‘%1’ for the second, and ‘%2’ for the third.

This version should work<sup>2</sup> whether you compile with `-masm=intel` or `-masm=att` options

---

### Footnotes

- <sup>1</sup>Although NASM Intel dialect and GAS's (GNU Assembler) Intel syntax are similar there are some differences. One is that NASM Intel syntax uses *[segment:disp+base+index*scale]* where a segment can be specified inside the `[]` and GAS's Intel syntax requires the segment outside with *segment:[disp+base+index*scale]*.
- <sup>2</sup>Although the code will work, you should place all these basic functions in the `ioaccess.h` file directly and eliminate them from the `.c` file that contains them. Because you placed these basic functions in a separate `.c` file (external linkage) the compiler can't optimize them as well as it could. You can modify the functions to be of type `static inline` and place them in the header directly. The compiler will then have the ability to optimize the code by removing function calling overhead and reduce the need for extra loads and stores. You will want to compile with optimizations higher than `-O0`. Consider `-O2` or `-O3`.
- **Special Notes Regarding OS Development**:

  1. There are many toy OSes (examples, tutorials, and *even* code on [OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page)) that do not work with optimizations on. Many failures are due to [bad/poor inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) or using undefined behaviour. Inline assembly should be used as a last resort. If your kernel doesn't run with optimizations on it is likely not a bug in the compiler (it is possible just not likely).
  2. Heed the advice in @PeterCordes answer regarding port access that may trigger DMA reads.

Comment: You can use dialect alternatives like `"inb {%1, %0 | %0, %1}"` to make it work both with and without `-masm=intel`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Answer (score 4):

**It's possible to writing code that works with or without `-masm=intel`, using dialect alternatives** for GNU C inline asm https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html  (This is a good idea for headers that other people might include.)

It works like `"{at&t stuff | intel stuff}"`: the compiler picks which side of the `|` to keep based on the current mode.

The major difference between AT&T vs. Intel syntax is that the operand-list is reversed, so usually you have something like `"inb {%1,%0 | %0,%1}"`.

**This is a version of @MichaelPetch's nice functions using dialect alternatives**:

```
// make this a header: these single instructions can inline more cheaply
// than setting up args for a function call
#include <stdint.h>

static inline
uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile ( "inb {%1, %0 | %0, %1}"
                   : "=a"(ret)
                   : "Nd"(port) );
    return ret;
}

static inline
void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t byte)
{
    asm volatile ( "outb {%1, %0 | %0, %1}"
                   :
                   : "a"(byte),
                     "Nd"(port) );
}

static inline
void io_wait(void) {
    outb (0x80, 0);
}
```

The Linux/Glibc `sys/io.h` macros sometimes use `%w1` to expand a constraint to the 16-bit register name, but using types of the right size also works.

If you want a memory-barrier version of these to take advantage of the fact that `in` / `out` are (more or less) serializing like a `lock`ed instruction or `mfence`, add a `"memory"` clobber  to stop compile-time reordering of memory access across it.

**If a port I/O can trigger a DMA read** of some other memory that you wrote recently, **you might also need a `"memory"` clobber for that**.  (x86 has cache-coherent DMA so you wouldn't have had to explicitly flush it, but you can't let the compiler reorder it after an `outb`, or even optimize away an apparently dead store.)

---

There's no support in GAS for saving the old mode, so using `.intel_syntax noprefix` inside your inline asm leaves you no way know whether to switch back to  `.att_syntax` or not.

But that wouldn't usually be sufficient anyway: you need to get the compiler to format operands in ways that match the syntax mode when filling in a template.  e.g. the port number needs to expand to `$imm` or `%dx` (AT&T<sup>1</sup>) vs. `dx` or `imm` without the `$` prefix.

Or for a memory operand, `[rdi + rax*4 + 8]` or `8(%rdi, %rax, 4)`.

But you still need to take care of reversing the operand list with `{ | }` yourself; the compiler doesn't try to do that for you.  It's purely a text-substitution into the template according to simple rules.

Footnote 1:  AT&T disassembly by `objdump -d` bizarrely uses `(%dx)` for the port number in the non-immediate form, but GAS accepts `%dx` or `(%dx)` on input, so an `"Nd"` constraint is usable, simply expanding to the bare register name.