# Why there is no parentheses wrapping around AL register?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Based on my understanding, %eax means the value contained by eax and (%eax) means go to the address reserved by eax

```
seta20.1:
inb $0x64, %al        # Wait for not busy
testb $0x2, %al
jnz seta20.1
movb $0xd1,%al        # 0xd1 −> port 0x64
outb %al, $0x64
```

Then, why there is no parentheses wrapping around %al?
Cuz if I want to move a val to an address by using register, i should do:

```
mov %ebx, (%eax)
```

right?

Comment: It's not clear which line of code you're referring to. But nowhere in this code is `al` being used as an address, hence no parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inb` is basically a load from IO space, into `%al`.  So the analogy would be `mov (%edx), %al`.

`%al` is the source (`out`) or destination (`in`) register, not a pointer, so of course there are never parens around `%al`.

If there were going to be parens anywhere, it would be around the IO space address, e.g. `(%dx)`.  Or `0x64()`.

But `inb` / `outb` don't use normal addressing modes, they uses an immediate or `%dx` for the IO-space address.  So AT&T syntax uses immediate or register syntax for them in the outb destination or inb source.  IO space is special and can't be addressed the same way as memory.

---

AT&T disassembly by `objdump -d` bizarrely does use `(%dx)` for the port number in the non-immediate form, but GAS accepts `%dx` or `(%dx)` on input which is [handy for inline asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962333/porting-att-inline-asm-inb-outb-wrappers-to-work-with-gcc-masm-intel/54962772#54962772).

And both assemble to the same machine code, of course; there is only one form of the instruction using DX at all with byte operand-size: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in.

```
   0:   ec                      in     (%dx),%al
```

`llvm-objdump -d` uses `inb     %dx, %al`

`(%dx)` is never a valid [*memory* addressing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866854/differences-between-general-purpose-registers-in-8086-bx-works-cx-doesnt): it's a 16-bit register other than BX,BP, SI or DI.