# Why does AT&T syntax use parens around DX in IN / OUT instructions like inb (%dx),%al

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, att

```
7c6f:   ec   in     (%dx),%al
```

Here my doubt is due to  `()`

Many places I wrote code this worked as take the value inside `(%dx)` and use it as memory location and value located there is value needed.

But here it should be doing just `in %dx,%al` ; and %dx hold port no
Just like `in 0x000,al`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in %dx, %al` assembles to the same `0xEC` byte of machine code, which `objdump -d` disassembles to `in  (%dx),%al` as you've found.

`llvm-objdump -d` does use the syntax you expected: `inb  %dx, %al` ; `inb  $128, %al`

AT&T syntax's use of `(%dx)` for the IO port number in `in` / `out`  is misleading since it's not a normal addressing mode; DX being the only option.  Presumably [the designers of AT&T syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244028/what-was-the-original-reason-for-the-design-of-att-assembly-syntax) wanted to represent the fact that you're reading or writing I/O address space.  But they did a bad job because it's inconsistent with their use of `in $0x80, %al` for immediate port numbers (as opposed to `0x80` for the port number using the same syntax as an absolute memory address).  GAS and LLVM don't even accept `in 0x80, %al`, so no, not "Just like `in 0x000,al`".

The `in` / `out` instructions access IO space, not memory address space.
The "addresses" in IO space are called port numbers.
IO space is still a thing in modern PCI-express, but most modern devices only have MMIO registers in device memory regions, not IO ports, because IO ports are slower to access.

---

`objdump -drwC -Mintel` disassembles to the same syntax Intel uses in [their manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in) for the only form of `in` that has a port in DX and byte operand-size.  Note the lack of `[dx]` brackets.

```
   0:   ec                      in     al,dx
   1:   e4 80                   in     al,0x80
```

`(%dx)` is [not one of the valid 16-bit addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866854/differences-between-general-purpose-registers-in-8086-bx-works-cx-doesnt), so that specific addressing mode is never valid for any other instruction.  But yes, `(%reg)` such as `(%edx)` or `(%bx)` is AT&T addressing-mode syntax for memory operands in instructions which allow a normal `reg/mem` operand such as `mov` or `add`.

See also [Why there is no parentheses wrapping around AL register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147378/why-there-is-no-parentheses-wrapping-around-al-register/58150970#58150970)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear, but I'll do my best to answer.

Using `(%dx)` as the first operand doesn’t work the way you think it does; for `in` and `out`,
`(%dx)` is *not* a memory operand, unlike how the same syntax is used for operands to other instructions.

The `IN` instruction takes two operands:

1. An immediate 8-bit value (like `$0x42`) or the `DX` register.
2. `AL`, `AX`, or `EAX`.

This means you cannot use a memory location for either operand.

Also, as seen in @PeterCordes’s answer, using `%dx` as a memory address is never valid.

For these two reasons, `(%dx)` cannot be interpreted as a memory address, so your assembler instead ignores the parentheses and interprets it as the register `%dx` alone.

**That means `in (%dx),%al` is exactly the same as `in %dx,%al`.**

If you want to take input from a port number stored in memory, you must first load the value into the `%dx` register:

```
mov (%something),%dx
in %dx,%al
```

For more information, consult page **3-494** in **Volume 2A** of the [Intel IA-32 reference manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html), or [this reference page](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html).

Comment: In AT&T syntax, `in (%dx), %al` is valid syntax for the same instruction as `in %dx, %al`.  In fact `objdump -d` prefers the first form; that code block in the question is real disassembly.  And yes this is insane and wrong looking.  Not the only bad / random decision the designers of AT&T syntax made (e.g. strange far-call / far-jmp `ljmp` syntax, although that's actually not crazy IIRC if you look at it the right way), not to mention the actual bugs in early AT&T unix assemblers which are now baked in to the syntax: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dBugs.html

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the correction. I mis-interpreted the question to mean that `in (%dx),%al` wasn’t working / assembling.

Comment: Yeah, it was not a clear question; I only figured out what it meant from having some memory of `(%dx)` showing up in AT&T syntax disassembly, and checking by trying it myself.